# Discord py purge channel

Tags: python, discord.py

I'm trying to make my Discord bot remove a few messages from a specified channel, I'm getting the error

`AttributeError: 'int' object has no attribute 'purge'`

The function is below

```
await clearChannel(3, 837017813357035560)
```

```
@bot.event
async def clearChannel(number, channel):
    await channel.purge(limit=number)
```

Comment: This is not an `event`, this looks rather like a `command`. What do you want to work with?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Welcome to Discord.py!

There are a few things going wrong here.

- You should be using the `@bot.command()` decorator - you are getting confused with `@bot.event`
- Commands are not designed to be triggered by other code - they are not regular methods in that sense. Your users will trigger the command with `!clearChannel` in the Discord chat, where `!` is the prefix you have set for the `bot` object.
- Your users should not have to manually pass in a channel ID for the command to work. This would be unecessarily complicated for the end users to deal with. Instead, you should just get the channel ID automatically from where the command message was sent.

Your code should be as follows;

```py
@commands.has_permissions(administrator=True)
@bot.command()
async def clear(ctx, number: int):
  await ctx.channel.purge(limit=number)
```

Some things I have added;

- I have added a check to make sure that only administrators can use this command. If you don't validate commands that can damage your server, once your bot is deployed any user will be able to delete any number of messages they want.
- `number: int` is a type hint. It will try to parse the `number` parameter to an int, which you want when you pass it into the `purge` method. If it can't be parsed, for example if it contains non-numerical characters you can handle that. Using type hints also increases code readability.

**EDIT:**

It seems like I have misunderstood your question. I gather you are looking for a non-command method which you can then implement in an event or something similar.

To do this, it would be essentially the same.

```py
async def clear_channel(channels, limit: int): # channels should be a list of discord.Channel objects
  for channel in channels:
    await channel.purge(limit=limit)
```

You can get the list of channels you need to pass in by either asking the administrator for the ID's of the channels, and using [get_channel()](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api.html?highlight=get_channel#discord.Client.get_channel) to get the `discord.Channel` object, and then append it to the list to be passed into the method above. There's also a more user-friendly way of doing this by passing in channel names and getting the channel objects that way, but I'll leave that up to you ;)

Comment: This is all great but the clearChannel is not supposed to be a command for players. I need the 2 channels to be cleared on bot startup and the bot will populate the channels with messages.

Comment: @JustinWilker I have edited my answer to reflect this.

Answer (score 0):

I believe the issue is that you are using the keyword `channel` for the argument of the function.  Since `channel` is an object type with discord.py, naming the argument `channel` will cause Python to believe the variable `channel` (which Python will interpret `837017813357035560` as `int`) within the inner scope of the function to be different than the outer scope `obj channel`.

Suggest naming to `chan` or something.  You will then need to initialize a `channel` type variable with the ID of the value `chan` for identification purposes.

Comment: No luck with that. I'm using the same function somewhere else with no issues.

Calling the function with 

`await clearChannel(bot.get_channel(int(config['statusChannel'])))`

works as intended


It is stored in the config file as `{"statusChannel": "837015522612215849"}
`